# Some advice to set up a proper scoring system for an answer based game

Tags: javascript, android, ios, sql-server, puzzle

I am developing an online question/answer game, and would like some help regarding my scoring system. Or some advice.

Basically, the game is a set of puzzles, each puzzle has a set of questions. The user goes through the questions and scores in one puzzle. In turn he does the same with the rest. This is an online user based game, which means each puzzle has a top 10 players ranks for each puzzle, plus an overall scoreboard for all puzzles combined. Moreover, the user can purchase extra puzzles. The game will offering a prize after some time period, and the more you play puzzles the larger chance you will have to win.

I neither have a problem with getting the user high score for each puzzle alone, nor do I have a problem with getting the top 10 players of that puzzle alone. The problem is when I think about the overall scoreboard.

My question is: How will I rank the top 10 players, knowing that the player that purchases more puzzles should have an edge, yet at the same time he cannot be better than another player who has higher percentages.

In details, consider this scenario:

```
- Player1
   * Free Puzzle 1: 60 points 80%
   * Free Puzzle 2: 80 points 85%
   * Paid Puzzle 1: 80 points 89%
-Player2
   * Free Puzzle 1: 50 points 72%
   * Free Puzzle 2: 40 points 66%
   * Paid Puzzle 1: 40 points 55%
   * Paid Puzzle 2: 70 points 80%
```

If we compare these two players, we will see that the second player has purchased more puzzles, but player 1 has scored better on them.

How can I solve this while preserving both aspects. The players' Spent money versus the players' performances. If I average them out like this,

```
Player 1: (80+85+89)/3 = 84.66%
Player 2: (72+66+55+80)/4 = 68.25%
```

and this will rank player 1 higher. Also take into consideration that the user might play 1 puzzle only and score higher than everyone else. I need to find a compromise.

Please note I do not need help with any code logic, this is just a general idea help of what I need to implement.

Thanks

Comment: Do you really need the final player scores to be a percentage?

Comment: @nickfalk Thanks for your comment. Basically, If i do not use percentages the point system will still evaluate that the player who pays for one puzzle will get a higher score even if he scored much less.

Answer (score 0):

There a probably a gazillion different ways to go about this, a few ideas from the top of *my* head:

A fairly simple way to accomplish the additional weight towards players buying more puzzles is actually using the number of paid puzzles as a parameter of some sort:

```
- Player1
   * Free Puzzle 1: 60 points 80%
   * Free Puzzle 2: 80 points 85%
   * Paid Puzzle 1: 80 points 89%
-Player2
   * Free Puzzle 1: 50 points 72%
   * Free Puzzle 2: 40 points 66%
   * Paid Puzzle 1: 40 points 55%
   * Paid Puzzle 2: 70 points 80%

Player 1: numberOfPaidPuzzles + (80+85+89)/3 = 86.66    
Player 2: numberOfPaidPuzzles + (72+66+55+80)/4 = 70.25
```

It is fairly lightly that the numberOfPaidPuzzles alone won't cut it so you probably want to weight this parameter somewhat, similar to the below example for the "reward player for playing more puzzles"-part of your question:

```
weightFactor = totalNumberOfAvailablePuzzles / n;
playerAverageScore = playerAverageScore * (weightFactor * totalNumberOfPuzzlesPlayed)
```

Comment: I will think about that @nickfalk and see what I can come up with.